# Nginx and PHP displays wrong IP address for localhost

Tags: php, linux, networking, nginx

I saw many questions from people with opposite problem, but not with mine.

Today nginx on my computer started sending wrong IP address for localhost to PHP. Last week, I could see `127.0.0.1` in my logs (`/var/log/nginx/access.log`) and in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. But from todays morning it's `10.0.0.60` which is my IP address in our company network.

First problem with that was when postgresql could not connect to database from php..

- **Nginx version**: 1.6.2
- **PHP version**: 5.5.12
- **Ubuntu**: 14.10

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong addresses?

Comment: Well, I know it is not wrong address but my actual address. But until today, it was always `127.0.0.1` and not my public IP address.

Comment: nginx just shows connection IP. So you have to find out why someone (you?) connects to nginx via `10.0.0.60`. Probably some network config modifictions, etc/

Comment: Last time I was on that computer was at friday last week and now I remember that I installed `iptables-persistent` for persisting iptables configuration.. But it shouldn't cause that right? I'll probably have to look into that as well

Comment: Of course I didn't mess with 127.0.0.1 or 10.0.0.60 in my iptables